# I want to get a random object from a JSON file in python

Tags: python, json

Just want a random object from JSON

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow; I think you should edit this question so the example data follows the Code of Conduct here: *"We don’t tolerate any language likely to offend or alienate people based on race, gender, sexual orientation, or religion"*. https://stackoverflow.com/conduct

Comment: Put these objects into a list `l`, and then use [`random.choice(l)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) to return a random element from that list.

Answer (score 1):

```
import json

#import json file
filter = "JSON file (*.json)|*.json|All Files (*.*)|*.*||"
filename = rs.OpenFileName("Open JSON File", filter)

#Read JSON data into the datastore variable
if filename:
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        datastore = json.load(f)
Random.choice(datastore)
```

I hope it works

Answer (score -1):

You can make jokes a list and use random:

```
import random
jokes=[{
    "body": "something"
},
{
    "body": "another"
},
{
    "body": "final"
}]
jokes[random.randint(0,len(jokes)]
```

Comment: I changed random to take into account a dynamic length